# How to select rows based on WHERE values from multiple rows with the same key-field MySQL

Tags: mysql

First I need the following selection:

```
select post_id, meta_key, meta_value 
from wp_postmeta 
where (meta_key = 'price_range' OR 
       meta_key = 'price_input' OR 
       meta_key = 'price_input_currency')
```

Then I get results like the following table:

[image]

**Then I need to filter out the record's depending on the two conditions below, by looking at each group of 3 rows with the same ID.**

Based on the two conditions below I should only see the group of rows in the red box.

①　First of all, only show groups which have `price_range` as a `meta_key`.

Show only rows which have `meta_key = 'price_range'` as one of the three rows per `post_id`.

②　Show only groups which have an empty `meta_value` for the meta_key: `price_input` but not an empty one for the meta_key: `price_range`.

So basically:

```
meta_key = 'price_input' AND (meta_value = '' OR meta_value = null)
```

AND

```
meta_key = 'price_range' AND (meta_value != '' OR meta_value != null)
```

I cannot use the AND between the rows with different `meta_key` but same `post_id`, but with OR I don't get what I need. So I'm confused how I should do this.

**The reason for my question:**

I'm trying to renew my data, and the field 'price_range' won't be used any longer. I will put that info in the two new fields: 'price_input' and 'price_input_currency'. That's why I want to quickly check which items still have something in 'price_range' but no data yet in the new fields.
So the red rows have a value for price_range but none for price_input. Those are the one's I'm looking for.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This is highly problematic.

Comment: Yes I do, I just didn't show it, because it's irrelevant I thought.

Comment: Please edit accordingly.

Comment: I don't see why I should post the row ID's as well? I don't see how that's relevant at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a maximum of three items for each post_id, each of which satisifies your where statements.
If so, you could use GROUP BY by and LIMIT

**Edited**

So I've been looking around for your question and I found a good reference
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

The not so good news when you navigate here is that the group by statement in your case may not be fixed (unlike the types apple/banana/etc in the link).

I believe if the number of groups isn't fixed, then you would have to resort to loops:

(This is just an example from the website, I'm gonna need to sleep a little before I modify this code to your needs)

```
set @num := 0, @type := '';

select type, variety, price
from (
select type, variety, price,
  @num := if(@type = type, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
  @type := type as dummy
from fruits
order by type, price
) as x where x.row_number <= 2;
```

Having said this, I would actually recommend not doing this logic on the database level (unless you're just doing this to learn) since the database is optimized to fetch and store variables. You would probably want to implement this logic on the server level or not use a RDB for this.

Sorry about the initially wrong post=(

Comment: I get `(1064): Syntax error near 'null)) GROUP BY post_id LIMIT 3' at line 8` on this one

Comment: It worked when I changed `meta_value NOT null` to `meta_value != null` but I only see 3 rows. I want to see all groups of 3 rows with the requirements I gave.

Comment: I rephrased the question!

Comment: Edited the answer-- Sorry about the previous answer, I'm a little sleep-deprived atm=(

Comment: I'm trying to renew my data, and the field 'price_range' won't be used any longer. I will put that info in the two new fields: 'price_input' and 'price_input_currency'. That's why I want to quickly check which items still have something in 'price_range' but no data yet in the new fields.⟶So the red rows have a value for price_range but none for price_input. Those are the one's I'm looking for.